# Mac renames itself automatically - host name is incorrect in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, network, command-line

I've got a handleful of macs (all with unique names) and on occasion it prompt a notice about saying another computer on the network as this name and adds a (2) or (3) to my mac.

How can I set the host name from the command line?

Comment: You need to clarify this into an actual question rather than a discussion topic - I can do it for you, but seems fair to give you the chance.

Comment: What router do you have? Have you enabled wake for network access on the problem macs?

Comment: It's a sonic wall NSA 3500. It's a school

Comment: Not enabled for network access from sleep

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can :

```
sudo scutil --set HostName "YourHostName"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "YourLocalHostName"
```

to change the computer name :

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "YourComputerName"
```

To check if everything is okay : `sudo scutil --get HostName`

Answer (score 3):

There is a couple ways to go about solving this problem.

The immediate change is to to open up Terminal, and issue the command

> sudo scutil --set HostName {your machine name here}

The next thing to do is to

> sudo pico /etc/hostconfig

Add the following line, followed by Ctrl+O, and then Ctrl+X

> HOSTNAME={your machine name here}

Finally reboot